# JAXBException: class ... nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: gradle, soap, jaxb, wsdl2java, wsimport

I have a wsdl file, when creating classes through wsimport I get an interface. This interface has @WebMethod for sending a MessagePrimaryContent.setAny request:

```
     /**
     * Sets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Element }
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setAny(Object value) {
        this.any = value;
    }
```

I also have an xsd scheme. Through xjc I form jaxb classes. It is the generated class that I need to pass to the setAny method. As a result of trying to send a request, I get an error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class ru.absenceofdebt.fts.artefacts.x.root._1_0.AbsenceOfDebtRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class ru.absenceofdebt.fts.artefacts.x.root._1_0.AbsenceOfDebtRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

It was necessary to do it urgently. Therefore, I had to add an ObjectFactory generated from xsd to @XmlSeeAlso as a temporary solution when building the project in the interface. But this is wrong. How can I do it correctly?

```
task editFile {

ext.fileService = "${buildDir}/generated/org/tempuri/ISMEVSERVICE.java"
dependsOn wsimport
dependsOn genJaxb

doLast() {
       ant.replaceregexp(
               file: fileService,
               match: "org.tempuri.ObjectFactory.class",
               replace: "ru.absenceofdebt.fts.artefacts.x.root._1_0.ObjectFactory.class, org.tempuri.ObjectFactory.class",
               byline: "true"
       )
    }
}
```